# Criar / Editar um arquivo no servidor (Apache)

Tags: php, apache, fopen

Com o seguinte código gostaria de criar um arquivo no servidor.

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $nomeArquivoLogDia = date('Ymd') . '-teste.log';

    if (file_exists($nomeArquivoLogDia)) {
        $arquivoLog = file($nomeArquivoLogDia, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);    
    } else {
        $arquivoLog = fopen($nomeArquivoLogDia, "w+");
    }
?>
```

Quando executo o php (http://localhost/teste.php) o arquivo não é gerado.

Alguem sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Verifique direito, pois eu testei aqui parece ok. Foi criado o arquivo.

Comment: voce usou wget ou php? pergunto pois preciso com wget. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente esse tipo de erro é permissão... Porém para saber ao certo procure o log de erro do seu host/servidor...

Se tiver acesso a máquina e ela for *nix, pode executar `cat /var/log/server_que_tu_usar/error.log`

Comment: Boa... era somente permissão mesmo. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @manga quase sempre é isso kkk, só toma cuidado quanto onde / pasta tu coloca permissão